# How to read headers from closed file and paste it in new sheet as column using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10+ files in a folder. i wants to copy all files headers to new sheet as a column. i am able to do this . But i wants to copy file name and sheet name also i tried but not getting data.
plz see the attchments and below code.

Code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
    Dim blank_cell As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
input_directory = Sheets("SystemConfiguration").Range("B2").Value & "\"
 Filename = Dir(input_directory & "*.xls")

'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(input_directory & Filename)
  Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
  Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  Variable = ActiveSheet.Name
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy

 Workbooks("newfile.xlsm").Activate
'ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each cell In ws.Columns(7).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell

 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    wbk.Close savechanges:=False
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

[image: Actual output i want]

this output is getting Mr.Mrig
[image: getting output like this]
Expecting this output
[image: Expecting this output]

Mr.Mrig this is my code after changes

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim variable As String
Dim rowCount As Long
 Dim add As Range
Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
input_directory = Sheets("SystemConfiguration").Range("B2").Value & "\"
 Filename = Dir(input_directory & "*.xls")
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(input_directory & Filename)
  Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
  Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  variable = ActiveSheet.Name
 ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy
 Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Activate
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(12).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
 Set add = Selection

 Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
 rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
 Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename
 Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = variable
    wbk.Close savechanges:=False
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some changes in your code.

Replace following line

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

to

```
 Selection.Value = Filename    '-->display file name in Column G(7)
 Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value = variable    '-->display sheet name in Column H(8)
 Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True    '-->display header in Column I(9)
```

**EDIT :**
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
 Dim rowCount As Long
 Dim add As Range
 Set add = Selection

 Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
 rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
 Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename
 Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = variable
```

Comment: by this changes only first column gets copied not all columns

Comment: @Amar - By saying first column do you mean `File Name` column.

Comment: i have added image to problem statement ....getting output like that image. if i have one file in folder.

Comment: the file name and sheet name is not not gets copied upto Email Column name

Comment: @Amar - Let me check.

Comment: getting error like Application defined or object defined error at this line "Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename"

Comment: @Amar - Did you write `Set add = Selection` and other two lines in my edited answer?

Comment: yes i have written Set add = Selection above these lines Selection.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
 rowCount = Selection.Rows.Count
 Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename
 Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = variable

Comment: i have added my whole code to problem statement please check it

Comment: @Amar - Is it possible for you to share your file?

Comment: why i am getting error for both these lines Range(add, add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 0)).Value = Filename
 Range(add.Offset(0, 1), add.Offset(rowCount - 1, 1)).Value = variable

Comment: closed all file those are open and deleted entire code and recopied whole code then its working well...........thank you for your answer